Using RAID-0 arrangement of dual NVMe devices for swap in Linux (to enable fast swap and hibernation)
I have converted a Supermicro server board into a workstation setup. The board has two very nice NVMe devices attached to it.  My file systems are mounted over network, and I am satisfied with their performance. My OS is Debian Linux.
I would like to use these NVMe devices for swapping. As I understand, the way the Linux handles swaps is that attaching two separate swap devices would result in a behavior functionally somewhat similar to RAID-0 in terms of performance. So far so good.
However, I would also like to allow the workstation to enter some meaningful sleep states. As far as I know, Supermicro boards are notoriously problematic with S3 sleep states. Therefore, my only option is some form of hibernation on Linux.
It appears that hibernation function requires that only a single swap device may be used to store the contents of RAM. I would like to take advantage of the combined performance of NVMe devices in that machine, since the amount of RAM is pretty large, and cutting the dumping and restoration time in half would matter. One possible solution that I see is to use dm-raid with RAID-0 configuration over these two NVMe units.

My first question is whether swapping over RAID-0 arranged dm-raid would be equivalent in terms of performance and reliability to the use of two swap devices.
My second question is whether I could actually use a dm-raid device as a swap device for hibernation.


Are you not using the NVMe devices for local storage? I don't completely understand your setup but I would say 1) RAID-0 should have superior I/O to separate swap devices (regardless of swap files or partitions) since they will be combined, and 2) I don't see any reason why a swap partition (or file) couldn't be on a virtual raid device.

My experience with Debian is that sleep is easily enabled and reliable, but hibernation is difficult to configure and has not been reliable, in the past. As for Supermicro, I cannot make any statement, but test sleep before discarding the idea.

@pzkpfw My storage is on a local ZFS file server, and the workstation boots from a local USB flash.  Both the root filesystem and data are mounted over NFS.  Now, given how fast the NVMe is, I think it's very fitting to use it as swap.  Also, note that tmpfs uses swap, so it also feels very appropriate not to use the local NVMe for other purposes.

@DrMoishePippik It appears that Supermicro does not really play well with S3 sleep (here, here), and it is quite possible that server motherboards are not easy to put to S3 sleep state (here and here).

@pzkpfw I know that, for example, zvol could not be used as swap (here, here).  I am concerned if a use of another layered blocks subsystem, like md-raid, may lead to similar issues.
